# Не могу загрузить проект в PyPi

Tags: python, pip

Проблема такова: собрал маленький модуль на питоне. Чисто чтобы проверить то, как работает система.
НО: при использование команды

```
py -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

или

```
py -m twine upload dist/*
```

Ввожу имя **token**
и в качестве пароля токен, сгенерированный на сайте (я зарегистрирован и потдвержден, с этим проблем не должно быть)

Однако, в конечном итоге ввыдает ошибку:

```
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information. for url: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

Пытался вместо токена вводить свой логин и пароль, зарегистрировался на сайте test.pipy.org, попробовал аналогичный способ, но нет. Не робит.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить сию проблему.

Comment: Это первый случай работы с токенами в Python?

Comment: Кстати, не test.pipy.org, а https://test.pypi.org/

Comment: Да, первый. Планирую написать модуль, тестировал как работает.